# Formating Json data from string and Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a situation where I need to format json data into below .

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ConvertDatadttoString(string appName)
{
    var sample = new List<SampleClass>
                     {
                        new SampleClass()
                            {
                                columns = new List<SampleItem>()
                                          {
                                               new SampleItem() {title = "NAME" },
                                               new SampleItem() {title = "COUNTY" },
                                          },
                                data = new List<List<string>>()
                                           {
                                               new List<string> { "John Doe", "Fresno" },
                                               new List<string> { "Billy", "Fresno" },
                                               new List<string> { "Tom", "Kern" },
                                               new List<string> { "King Smith", "Kings" },
                                           }
                            }
    };

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(sample);

    return json;
}

public class SampleClass
{
    public IEnumerable<SampleItem> columns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data { get; set; }
}

public class SampleItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

The above code is giving the correct json data for me, but I need to do some modifications in the code so that it can intake data from my source.First of all `new SampleItem() {title = "NAME" },` needs to be populated from stringarray which is like

```
string columnNames = "Name,County";
string[] arrcolumnNames = columnNames.Split(',');
```

and secondly,`new List<string> { "John Doe", "Fresno" },` needs to be populated from .net `DataTable`. How to do it.

I tried to add for loop and add the values from string array:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= arrcolumnNames.Length; i++)
{
    new SampleItem() { title = arrcolumnNames[i] }
}
```

but I'm getting an error.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I tried to add `for(int i=0;i<=arrcolumnNames.Length;i++){
                 new SampleItem() 
            
                { title = arrcolumnNames[i] }
               }` but its giving compile error

Comment: "I'm getting an error": which error are you getting??

Comment: Please reformat your code sample(s). It is not just an inconvenience to potential readers, it could have the effect of driving them away. Formatting code matters, and posting badly formatted code sends a signal that the post is not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static string ConvertDatadttoString(string appName = "")
{

    var columnNames = "Name,County";
    var employees = CreateEmployeesTable();
    var sample = new List<SampleClass>
    {
        new SampleClass()
        {
            columns = columnNames.Split(',').Select(x=> new SampleItem
            {
                title = x
            }),
            data = employees.AsEnumerable().Select(row=> new List<string>
            {
                row.Field<string>("EmployeeName"),
                row.Field<string>("Company")
            })
        }
    };

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(sample);

    return json;
}
```

The private method `CreateEmployeesTable`

```
private DataTable CreateEmployeesTable()
{
    var table = new DataTable()
    {
        Columns = { "EmployeeName", "Company" },
        TableName = "Employees"
    };
    table.Rows.Add("John Doe", "Fresno");
    table.Rows.Add("Billy", "Fresno");
    table.Rows.Add("Tom", "Kern");
    table.Rows.Add("King Smith", "Kings");
    return table;
}
```

**Update**

[DataRowExtensions.Field Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field(v=vs.110).aspx) has five overload.

The integer overload that accepts an integer (index). If you want to get the first column the index will be 0. So call it like `row.Field<string>(0)`

Comment: Now I am getting Implicitly typed local variable can not have multiple declarators at ` var sample = new List<SampleClass>`

Comment: you should have replaced your local variable with mine. not amended

Comment: I will check and let you know.Thanks

Comment: Its working almost Naveen.Thanks. Only thing I wanted to ask is that "Is there a way by which we can access the value of the datatable without giving column names and update the code at `data = employees.AsEnumerable().Select(row=> new List<string>
            {
                row.Field<string>("EmployeeName"),
                row.Field<string>("Company")
            })
`